# Control processes in container by supervisor

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, supervisord

I have container with php-fpm as main process. Is possible create another container with supervizor as main proces to run and controll some daemon process in the php container? For example, in the php conainer there is some consumer that consume messagess from rabbitMQ. I want to control that consumers by supervisor, but I don't want to run supervizor in the php container. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** I have a container running the php-fpm as its main process. Is possible to create another container with `supervisor` as the main process to run and control other daemon processes in the php container?

**A:** I have reconstructed your problem statement a little, let me know if it do not make sense.

Short answer, possible. **However** you don't want to have nested containers within one as this is considered `anti-pattern` and is not the desire `micro-service` architecture.

Typically you would only have one `main process` running in a container. This is so that when the `process` dies the container will stops and exit. Hence not bringing the other working `processes` with it.

An ideal architecture would be to have one container for the `rabbitmq` and another container for the `php` process. Easiest way to spun them up on a same `docker network` would be through a `docker-compose` file.

You may be interested in the following attributes `links`/`depends_on` and `expose` to `port forward` your rabbitMq's port into your `php` container.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Comment: You asked and responded your own question just so you can tell some person that they are doing things wrong. You totally missed the question. amazing